# How to add text between two or more results when using =filter()?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(A6="","",IFERROR(FILTER($B$2:$B$4&$C$2:$C$4,$A$2:$A$4=A6)))
```

returns JOB8000 vs JOB $8000.

[image: VIEW IMAGE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(A6="",,IFERROR(FILTER($B$2:$B$4&" $"&$C$2:$C$4,$A$2:$A$4=A6)))
```

[image: 0]